# Use a react element in the tag <title>

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have no idea about Reacts, and I don't even know all the basics of Javascript, so I'd really appreciate your help. 
I wanted to use a react element that's inside a modal window as a title for the page (I'll use a script for greasemonkey), but I'm not being able to identify/recall the element. The code of the script and of the html page are something like:

```js
setInterval(function() {
document.title = "Time Left" + "BBB"; // I know this is wrong, it's just to show what I'm looking for
}, 1000);
```

```html
<div data-react-class="require('reactComponents/common/ShowModal')['default']" 
data-react-props="{
"modalType":"ProjectDetailsModal",
"modalHeader":"Modal Window",
"modalOptions":{
"AAA":"BBB",
"CCC":"DDD",
"children":"Modal Window Details"}">
<a href="#" data-reactid=".1">Modal Window Details</a></div>
```

I'd like to change the name of the page to BBB (it's a name that always changes, while AAA and CCC remain the same). I'd appreciate any help and/or hint, thank you very much!

Comment: Why are you not using state to save your title ?

Comment: I don't have access to the HTML file, I'd like to create a script to modify the appearance of the original document. The javascript code I'm using works fine, I'm just not able to pass the "BBB" variable there because I don't know how to recall it.

Comment: @Pl4nn3r Your post is all over the place. `<title>` can never be anything but text. Just to be clear, the `<title>` is in wrapped by your `<head>`. I get the sneaking suspicion that you might be confused as to what is in `<title>`, because the text inside it is not rendered on the page itself. It's the name of the window (the tab name).

Comment: Hi Andrew, thank you for your reply! I know what the tag title does, and the javascript code I wrote (with few modifications I didn't write here) actually changes it (it's a greasemonkey script). What I wanna do is to get the value of the element "BBB" of the modal window from the source code, before the modal windows gets opened (I tried to extract it as an unknown substring between two known strings, AAA and CCC, but it didn't work) and to "copy/paste" that value to the tag title.

Comment: @Pl4nn3r What do you mean by "element"? Where is this data located? If you tag me I will get a notification so I know when you reply.

Comment: @Andrew thank you for your time! I call "element" the string "BBB", it's what appears in the modal window ex "AAA=Name, BBB=John", "CCC=Family Name", DDD=Doe" etc. It's a value/element/text found in a page, and I'm looking for some javascript command to tell the script to look for this string "BBB" in the source code, and to copy it in the title of the tab. Something like this script https://greasyfork.org/it/scripts/28919-ebay-countdown-in-title-bar/code

Comment: @Pl4nn3r So to be clear, there is a modal that comes up, and in that window, you very specifically see, on your website, these characters: "AAA=Name, BBB=John", "CCC=Family Name", DDD=Doe". You want to grab the text from inside this modal?

Comment: Yes @Andrew, I'd like to copy "BBB" and to use it in the tag title, but I need to do it from the source code, because if I do it from the modal I get an ID like .6.0.0.1.0.0 and the title shows the writing "undefined". To finally get the title "BBB" I need to actually click in the modal window, but I don't want to perform this action, I'd like to grab the value BBB before it becomes part of the modal window. Hope I've been clear enough, thanks again!

Comment: @Pl4nn3r Ok. I understand now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem with what you’re asking for is the fact that it is impossible to grab content that doesn’t exist in the DOM (what’s currently rendered). What you CAN do though, is be sneaky about how that component gets mounted. Using inline styles in your jsx, you have the option of mounting-but hiding an html element that your user cannot see. For example, you can set the modal load automatically with the page, but with to a height as 0px and overflow hidden when the page load. And then clicking the button changes the modal back to its default settings. That way the modal’s content exists when you need it, but can’t be seen until you want it to.

```
`class App extends Component {
   constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      showModal: false
     }
   }
   showModal() {
     this.setState({showModal: true})
   }
   render() {
     return (
       <div>
        //all of your normal content
       <button onClick={() => this.showModal()}>
         show modal
       </button>
       //div wrapper that will force your modal to be hidden when component mounts
       <div style={this.state.showModal ? null : {'height': '0px', 'overflow': 'hidden'}}>
        <Modal>
          Modal stuff
        </Modal>
      </div>
    </div>
   )
  }
}`
```

Comment: Hello @Andrew, thanks again for your time and for your help! I didn't try your code, but I'm afraid it's not going to work for me, because BBB it's always a different value (I don't know how I can look for a value === BBB if I don't know which one is it, it could be John, Jack, Brian etc.), and BBB doesn't have an ID before being rendered on the modal window: I need to catch it before there is a click on the modal, by telling the script that it must look for the text between "AAA" and "CCC" (they stay the same) and use it in my title. Thank you again! :)

Comment: @Pl4nn3r I changed my answer completely because I realized your request was different from what I answered. Let me give you a quick example of what I think you're looking for in a small React Component example.

Comment: I read your answer @Andrew, and it makes a lot of sense to me, this is a way to fix the problem that might actually work fine! Thank you very much for the suggestion, I will work on this direction! :)

Comment: I saw now your edit, and I'm sure that it will make my life a lot easier with the code to be modified on the script. Thank you very much once again @Andrew, your help and suggestions have been really precious! :)

Comment: @Pl4nn3r Just happy I could help. The devil is in the details, so just keep in mind that what I have exactly there will almost certainly not work for you needs. Just the general concept. If you don't mind, could you mark this as solved? :)

Comment: Hehehe, yes, you're right, always be careful about the tiny, little details.. ^_^ Thank you again for the suggestions, I think I'm gonna spend the night working on this.. :)